# Android Camera 2 FocusArea

Tags: android, android-camera

In the old camera api I had the Camera.Parameters's setFocusArea that I could specify a rect to the camera focus, but in the new Camera2 api I can specify only the focus distance. Anyone knows how to specify a rect to the camera focus?

The desired effect is to implement focus on touch. I found a lot of answers here in Stack Overflow to implement focus on touch in new camera api, but no one lets me specify a Rect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the autofocus metering region in the CaptureRequest with the
[CONTROL_AF_REGIONS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_AF_REGIONS) key.  There are corresponding keys for the auto-exposure and auto-white balance regions as well.

Comment: I'm fetching `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rect.left must be nonnegative`. could you please guide me!

Comment: You're probably using the old camera API's definitions for the region, which was (-1000, 1000) for the current FOV.   Camera2 does not use that definition; all regions are based on the active pixel array (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE )

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code. I've implemented [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.hardware.camera2.params.MeteringRectangle) `onAreaTouchEvent` but don't know `clamp` function inside it